# DataSource Select Parameter from GET value

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How can I use the value of a GET form value as a SelectParameter?

**Note:** Both C# and VB.NET answers are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [QueryStringParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx)